# push_backing into list of pointers causes memory leak

Tags: c++, visual-studio, list, memory-leaks

I am trying to find memory leak with Visual Leak Detector.
It shows me `m_neighbors.push_back(ent);` causes leak.

(brief callstack = NeighborCalculatorDummy -> foreach -> list -> allocate)

I use it as `NeighborCalculatorDummy<Entity *>`, so pushback should just insert pointer in list without any allocation.
All pointers to entities which come through addEntity are deleted elsewhere in code...

How is it possible for `push_back` to cause a leak?

```
template <typename entity_type>
class NeighborCalculatorDummy
{
public:
    inline void addEntity(const entity_type & entity)
    {
        m_entities.push_back(entity);
    }

    void calculateNeighbors(const vector_type & position, flt32 radius)
    {
        flt32 rSq = radius*radius;
        m_neighbors.clear();

        std::for_each(m_entities.begin(), m_entities.end(), [&](entity_type ent){
            if(lengthSq(ent->getPosition() - position) <= rSq)
                m_neighbors.push_back(ent);
        });
    }

private:
    std::vector<entity_type> m_entities;
    std::list<entity_type> m_neighbors;
};
```

**edit**

here is the code around NeighborCalculator

```
//#1 
std::list<Vehicle *> vehicles;
vehicles.push_back(new Vehicle);
vehicles.push_back(new Vehicle);
vehicles.push_back(new Vehicle);

//#2 
NeighborCalculatorDummy<Vehicle *> neighborCalculator = new NeighborCalculatorDummy<Vehicle *>();

std::for_each(vehicles.begin(), vehicles.end(), [&](Vehicle * vehicle){
    neighborCalculator->addEntity(vehicle);
});

//#3 impl of addEntity
template <typename entity_type>
void NeighborCalculatorDummy<entity_type>::addEntity(const entity_type & entity)
{
    ...
    m_entities.push_back(entity);  //m_entities is - std::vector<Vehicle *> 
}

//#4 end of program
delete neighborCalculator;

std::for_each(vehicles.begin(), vehicles.end(), [&](Vehicle * vehicle){
    delete vehicle;
});
```

Comment: Where are you deleting the pointer with dynamically allocated memory? Where did you allocate it?

Comment: You probably need to add more information, as what is the type of `entity_type`, and how the `NeighborCalculatorDummy` is used (is it being destroyed?) If the memory that is leaked was acquired in the `push_back` call, that seems to indicate that the list is not getting destroyed correctly.

Comment: Does CRT memory leak detector shows the same leak?

Comment: Add _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG) | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF) to the beginning of the program. Are memory leak reported when program is closed?

Comment: @Als see edit of my question, i put it there

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas `NeighborCalculatorDummy` is allocated dynamically and is deleted at the end of the program. See edit please

Comment: @AlexFarber yes, CRT detector show exactly same amount of leak

Comment: @relaxxx: Are you sure that you are not leaking the pointer? Print the result of the `new` (pointer) right after it completes, and print the pointer right before the `delete`. Besides that, analyze the output of the tool that is diagnosing the leak to see what it actually says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have omitted virtual destructor in Entity's parent. That is why pushbacking it caused a leak.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that `entity_type` is a pointer (judging from the for_each lambda).

You probably wanted to use

```
 NeighborCalculatorDummy<SomeEntity>
```

instead of

```
 NeighborCalculatorDummy<SomeEntity*>
```

in some other place of your code (not shown)

Of course the lambda would then be spelled differently:

```
[&](const entity_type& ent){
        if(lengthSq(ent.getPosition() - position) <= rSq)
            m_neighbors.push_back(ent);
    }
```

and perhaps more similar spots that assumed the type of entity_type needed dereferencing.

Alternatively, you could use

- `vector<std::shared_ptr<entity_type> >` instead
- Boost Pointer Containers

These might be more appropriate when your entities are polymorphic types or non-copyables/movables. However, it is also likely more work to change you code around

Comment: While it might be possible that the user would want that different version, that does not explain the memory leak. It is not the `SomeEntity` object the one that is not being deallocated, but rather the list node (which is what is acquired from the `allocator` inside `push_back`)

Comment: I do not want to use it like `NeighborCalcDummy<Some>` because It would create list of others Entities in `NeighborCalcDummy`. I want to work just with pointers with this class (since stl doesn't allowed create vecotr/list of references)

Answer (score 0):

With this definition, depending on entity_type, the code will leak or not.

- If entity_type is a pointer, the default destructor will just call the destructor of vector. This will free the memory allocated for these pointers, but it will not call delete on them. If this class "owns" the items inside the vector and needs to free them, you need to add a destructor that calls delete for all items inside the vector. In this case, you might think about the template parameter as well as it does not make clear that a pointer is needed here.
- If entity_type is a value type, the default destructor is sufficient as the copies placed into the vector will be deleted by the destructor of the vector.